# Combine [backup] and [backups]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

We've got a few questions tagged [backup](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup) and a few more than that tagged [backups](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backups).  Makes no difference to me, but it would seem that backups is more inclusive to the act of backing up, as well as the resultant files, whereas backup seems more like the verb.

Comment: i agree, backups is an active way of describing the actual procedure.

Comment: I'm also in favor of the plural, in most cases actually - unless the plural is for some reason just awkward to say, or incorrect (e.g. someone didn't realize a tag was a mass noun)